# Importing psutil causes ImportError

Tags: python, python-import, psutil

I'm trying to get `psutil` to work on our server. It is running AIX. There is no `pip`. So, I downloaded the [repo from github](https://github.com/Infinidat/psutil/tree/aix)(AIX build of psutil), `cd` into it, and ran Python CLI.

Now, trying to do `import psutil` causes an ImportError.

```
bash-4.2$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 16 2013, 14:02:06) [C] on aix6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "psutil/__init__.py", line 163, in <module>
    from . import _psaix as _psplatform
  File "psutil/_psaix.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_aix as cext
ImportError: cannot import name _psutil_aix
>>> import psutil              ## IMPORTING AGAIN THE SAME SESSION CAUSES DIFFERENT ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "psutil\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import _common
ImportError: cannot import name _common
```

What can I do here? Installing the module locally using `python setup.py install --user` is also not working:

```
bash-4.2$ python setup.py install --user
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psutil._psutil_aix' extension
xlc_r -ma -I/opt/freeware/include -DAIX_GENUINE_CPLUSCPLUS -Wl,-brtl -g -DNDEBUG -O2 -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=532 -DPSUTIL_AIX=1 -I/opt/freeware/include/python2.7 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.aix-7.1-2.7/psutil/_psutil_common.o
unable to execute xlc_r: No such file or directory
error: command 'xlc_r' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried doing the same with the `tweepy` package which runs perfectly(given `six`, `requests`, and `requests_oauthlib` are already installed).

EDIT: Just to make clear this is not limited to AIX, I've tried doing the same on Windows, and it gives the same error.

Comment: If you want to install a module without admin rights you can add the `--user`flag to the pip command :)

Comment: Ah, yes I know that, but since this is a work machine, `pip` is not there at all.

Comment: Try `python -m pip install psutil --user` it could work :)

Comment: That gives `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be downloading the wheel from PyPi
([psutil on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil))

Then open it with a zip program (7zip or similar).
In there should be a `psutil` folder. Place this folder next to your script and try to import it.

Comment: I edited the question to the actual situation. I believe there are no wheels for the AIX version of `psutil`

Answer (score 0):

AIX is currently not supported by psutil although it will in the next major release.

Comment: I know! I've been following [this PR](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/pull/1123) closely. But I was trying the [fork](https://github.com/Infinidat/psutil/tree/aix) by wiggin15(aix branch). Can you give an estimate when the next release might happen?

Comment: The import using the same method does not work in Windows either.